# Dictation (Voice Recognition) Function has Stopped Working

Tags: voice-recognition

I have a Samsung Galaxy J3 Luna Pro whose dictation listening function has recently stopped working.  When I press the microphone button now to dictate, the blue button indicating it is listening to dictation comes on for only a split second and then goes off, and the words "try again" appear on the screen. (Previously the blue circular button would stay on the screen for a while while I would dictate).

To try to remedy this, I have gone into settings > language and input > virtual keyboard > Samsung keyboard > reset settings, however it has not worked. I have also tried "clear personalized data," but this has not worked either.

Under virtual keyboard > Google voice typing, everything looks normal there too.

The Internet connection is not an issue, as it works fine. This has been plaguing me for about two months now through multiple reboots of the phone, yet I cannot figure out how to gain my dictation function back.

There is about 675 MB of free space on the device, which should be enough for me to dictate out a couple of sentences at least. Even if there are no apps open, or only one app open, it still happens, so it is not a RAM issue either.  I can't even dictate out a single word before the blue circle quickly turns off and it says "try again." It is 100% not working all the time. It does not 'sometimes work.'

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Is the only recourse reinstalling Android?

If I have no choice but to reinstall Android, how do I backup all my apps before doing so?

I am running Android version 7.0.

Thank you very much.